# Scaling error and Information cirteria in lmfit

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, weighted, lmfit

I am using lmfit for solving a non-linear optimization problem. It works fine to the point where I am trying to implement a measurement error as the standard deviation of the dependent variable y (sigma_y). My problem is, that I cannot interpret the Information criteria properly. When implementing the `return (model - y)/(sigma_y)` they just raise from really low to very high values.

i.e. [left: `return (model - y)` -weighting-> right: `return (model - y)/(sigma_y)`]:

- chi-square 0.00159805 -> 47.3184972
- reduced chi-square 1.7756e-04 -> 5.25761080 [expectation value is 1](https://www.astro.rug.nl/software/kapteyn/kmpfittutorial.html#reduced-chi-squared) || [SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43421482/python-lmfit-reduced-chi-square-too-small-after-weighted-fit)
- Akaike info crit -93.2055413 -> 20.0490661 [the more negative, the better](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/fitting.html)
- Bayesian info crit -92.4097507 -> 20.8448566 [the more negative, the better](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/fitting.html)

My guess is, that this is somehow connected to bad usage of lmfit (wrong calculation of Information criteria, bad error scaling) or to a general lack of understanding these criteria (to me reduced chi-square of 5.258 (under-estimated) or 1.776e-4 (over-estimated) sounds like a really poor fit, but the plot of residuals etc. looks okay for me...)

Here is my example code that reproduces the problem:

```
import lmfit
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = np.array([1.42774324, 1.45919099, 1.58891696, 1.78432768, 1.97403125,
       2.17091161, 2.02065766, 1.83449279, 1.64412613, 1.47265405,
       1.4507    ])
sigma_y = np.array([0.00312633, 0.00391546, 0.00873894, 0.01252675, 0.00639111,
       0.00452488, 0.0050566 , 0.01127185, 0.01081748, 0.00227587,
       0.00190191])
x = np.array([0.02372331, 0.07251188, 0.50685822, 1.30761963, 2.10535442,
       2.90597497, 2.30733552, 1.50906939, 0.7098041 , 0.09580686,
       0.04777082])
offset = np.array([1.18151707, 1.1815602 , 1.18202847, 1.18187962, 1.18047493,
       1.17903493, 1.17962602, 1.18141625, 1.18216907, 1.18222051,
       1.18238949])
parameter = lmfit.Parameters()
parameter.add('par_1', value = 1e-5)
parameter.add('par_2', value = 0.18)

def U_reg(parameter, x, offset):
    par_1 = parameter['par_1']
    par_2 = parameter['par_2']
    model = offset + 0.03043211217 * np.arcsinh(x / (2 * par_1)) + par_2 * x
    return (model - y)/(sigma_y)

mini = lmfit.Minimizer(U_reg, parameter, fcn_args=(x, offset), nan_policy='omit', scale_covar=False)
regr1 = mini.minimize(method='least_sq') #Levenberg-Marquardt
print("Levenberg-Marquardt:")
print(lmfit.fit_report(regr1, min_correl=0.9))

def U_plot(parameter, x, offset):
    par_1 = parameter['par_1']
    par_2 = parameter['par_2']
    model = offset + 0.03043211217 * np.arcsinh(x / (2 * par_1)) + par_2 * x
    return model - y

plt.title("Model vs Data")
plt.plot(x, y, 'b')
plt.plot(x, U_plot(regr1.params, x, offset) + y, 'r--', label='Levenberg-Marquardt')
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

I know that it might be more convient to implement weighting via `lmfit.Model`, due to multiple regressors I want to keep the `lmfit.Minimizer` method. My python version is 3.8.5, lmfit is 1.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in order for the magnitude of chi-square to be meaningful (for example, that it be around (N_data - N_varys), the scale of the uncertainties has to be correct -- giving the 1-sigma standard deviation for each observation.

It's not really possible for lmfit to detect whether the sigma you use has the right scale.

Comment: Currently the 1-sigma standard deviation is calculated by `pandas.DataFrame.std` with a normalization by N-1. Prior to this, I also prepare the data to approximate static behavior, that´s why the [standard deviations](https://imgur.com/GVCDWra) are pretty low. Right now [unweighted Fit](https://imgur.com/Tuu9uYZ) clearly outruns [weighted Fit](https://imgur.com/LarHSi5), so I guess that I have to accept it and fit with `return (model - y)` when deviations tend to zero?

Comment: @FabianPascher what does "with a Normalization by N-1" mean?  You almost certainly want to scale "model-data" by the uncertainties in the data.  Using the 1-sigma "standard deviation" of the data is a fine approach.  There is no N-1 in that.  It's just (and exactly) the square-root of the variance.     I also have no idea what "now unweighted Fit clearly outruns weighted Fit" means.  You mean in the sense that one is faster than the other?

Comment: @M Newville You can divide the _sum(x_i - my)^2_-numerator in the variance either by N (population) or by N-1 (sample - also called "unbiased estimator of standard deviation"), with N as the number of measurements. Since my groups are very large in N, this doesn't make a big [difference](https://jpst.it/2xeRZ) - and was a bit misleading to mention... _You mean in the sense that one is faster than the other?_ - No, I meant that 1-sigma approach with the given sigma_y led to worse regression results (i.e. information criteria, plots I posted in the comment before).

Comment: @M Newville I am currently searching for different approaches to improve the regression result of my example code. My "reference" is the `return (model - y)` which seems to return the best set of parameters (with sadly really small reduced chi-square **1.8e-4**). Applying weights like 1-sigma leads to really high reduced chi-square **5.3**, which can be compensated by 2-sigma, but somehow feels like cheating and only corrects reduced chi-square **1.3**, while Akaike **4.8** and Bayesian **5.6** are still positive. The 2-sigma parity plot stays basically the same as 1-sigma.

Comment: Here are some parity plots of [no-weight](https://imgur.com/gLFerkr), [1-sigma](https://imgur.com/RYcnLRh) and [2-sigma](https://imgur.com/naJKEZ1)

Comment: Demanding that reduced chi-square be very close to 1 (say, being between 0.5 and 1.5) requires two things: a) that the model is a perfectly accurate description of your data, including that there are no systematic errors in your data -- that all the variance in the data is statistical fluctuation, and b) that you have a very accurate estimate of those 1-sigma fluctuations.  To be clear, I don't mean that those should be true "in principle", but specifically for the actual data. For the kinds of measurements I work with, neither of these is ever true.

Comment: Your plots all look about the same to me -- should one of these be "obviously better"?  If you want to convey that, you'll have to include error bars for each value.

Comment: To _a)_: After data preparation there might be heteroscedasticity left in some of the regressors that define the offset and the dependent variable y, there are some groups that fail hypothesis testing (Shapiro, Anderson, D'Agostino, etc. | alpha = 0.05) with normal distribution, weak multicollinearity might also have a small impact. To _b)_: Each observation contains around 110 measurements, 70 % of the observations are tested as normal distributed (30 % as Gaussian-like or complete fails). So 1-sigma should be approximately right.

Comment: According to Information criteria, the non-weighted fit is much better (negative Akaike & Bayesian, reduced chi-square of 1.7756e-04 ). Statistics of the parity plot show small improvements when using no-weights instead of 1-sigma (identical result to 2-sigma) weights. MAE becomes 0.002 smaller, RMSE 0.014 and RMSE/Std(y) decreases by 0.01 when fitting on the non-weighted `return (model - y)`. Here are the plots with 1-sigma error bars: [unweighted](https://imgur.com/YlPfjXi) & [1-sigma weighted](https://imgur.com/XffNr7H).

Comment: To my mind, non-weighted is better than 1-sigma weighted. But I can be wrong, here are some additional plots of the residuals: [unweighted fit](https://imgur.com/6TUdTst) & [1-sigma weighted fit](https://imgur.com/TgRfLJk) (error bars in 1-sigma weighted not really visible due to high residuals).

Comment: "non-weighting" is weighting by 1.0.  If you have a better estimate of the uncertainties in the data than "all uncertainties have the value 1.0", you should use that.  If weighting by 1.0 gives a better result, then maybe your careful and precise statistics are simply wrong.  If a plot of the data with error bars and the best fit model shows systematic disagreement far outside the error bars then all the careful and precise statistics will not really improve the obvious conclusion of "not a good fit".